# Can't get same origin iframe body on IE10?

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-10, specifications

I've created a page with an empty iframe on it.  I can then select the iframe document and navigate to it's body:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var body = doc.body;
console.log("Body is", body);
```

In firefox and chrome this gives me the body object. In IE10 it gives me null.

[Here is a Jsbin demonstrating the issue.](http://jsbin.com/odabeq/1/edit) Open up the JS, Console, Output panels and click "Run With JS".

Two questions:

1. How do I get access to the iframe's body in a cross-browser manner?
2. Which is the correct "to-spec" behavior?

Comment: did you try wrapping the code in `window.onload`?

Comment: In my actual application the page is loaded long before it runs, in the example it is not but jsbin appends scripts to the bottom so it should not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over a year later but I believe the solution was to call

```
doc.open()
//make any modifications
doc.close()
//at this point doc.body will not be null
```

This made things work in a fairly consistent manner cross browser

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem earlier today. It seems IE, at least 9 and 10, doesn't create the iframe body correctly (when I used the developer tools I was able to see a body tag inside the iframe, but like you wasn't able to call it), when there's no specified src. It gives you null cause it doesn't exist.

The answer, to whether there is a cross browser manner to access the iframe's body, is no. BUT, you could use a workaround. First, check if the iframe body exist, if not, then create it.

Your code would look like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

// The workaround
if (doc.body == null) {       // null in IE
    doc.write("<body></body>");
}

var body = doc.body;
console.log("Body is", body);
```

Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1686774.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me cross-browser:

```
var doc=ifr.contentWindow||ifr.contentDocument;
if (doc.document) doc=doc.document;
var body=doc.getElementByTagName("body")[0];
```